# Proper Method To Overwrite Bundle Block

Tags: magento-1.8, module, overrides, bundled-product, bundle

I am creating a module that will add a custom field for bundle product. For that I came to a situation in which, I have to overwrite the core block `Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option`. However my overwriting seems to be not working.

More specific to the problem, I need to overwrite

1. `__construct()` - This method is using to set the template that is need to render for options (When we click on `Add Options` under tab `Bundle Items` in bundle product edit page, this template is going to render). Currently it is set to template `app/desig/frontend/<package>/<theme>/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml`. I need to set it to a `custom option.phtml` file so that I can add my custom field `without altering any code in core files`.
2. `getOptions()`  - need to edit this function also. This is also essential, since I need to set details of my custom field along with details of existing fields in this function.

***What I have tried***

`etc/config.xml`

```
 <config>
     ----
     <global>
         ------
         <blocks>
             <bundle>
                 <rewrite>
                     <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
                           Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option
                    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
                </rewrite>
             </bundle>  
     </global>
 </config>
```

`Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Bundle/Option.php`

```
 <?php
Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option 
{

    /**
     * Bundle option renderer class constructor
     *
     * Sets block template and necessary data
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->setTemplate('programmerrkt/customfieldinbundle/bundle/product/edit/bundle/option.phtml');
        $this->setCanReadPrice(true);
        $this->setCanEditPrice(true);
    }
}
```

However this overwriting seems to be not working.After including this code in my module, when I click on `Add Options`, the button is not working at all.

So my question is,

*what should I do if I want to alter this default class ?*

*Whether I am in right direction ?*

*Is it even possible to do this ?*

Eagerly waiting for responses. Thanks.

Comment: Any chance the issue is to do with the white space before `Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option` in your config.xml?

Comment: @DavidManners:  Ya that was the issue. I spent lot of time (more than one week !) in order to find that error. :( It was small but BIGGEST mistake that I have made. My bad :(

Comment: @DavidManners : I forgot to put that an answer. I will do it right now. Thanks for notify this :)

Comment: I would suggest maybe closing it as I am not sure how much people can take away from this question.

Comment: @DavidManners: I will close the question after put my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that I made here was small. But it consumed my lot of time to found out it. This was the error

```
            <rewrite>
                 <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
                       Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option
                </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
            </rewrite>
```

Please not the unwanted space that exist in between the node `<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option />`. Correct code is this.

```
             <rewrite>
                  <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>Programmerrkt_Customfieldinbundle_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Bundle_Option</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_bundle_option>
            </rewrite>
```

So the lesson I studied

***"Even simple spaces that we leave inside config file may product serious effect. So beware simple spaces. They are dangerous"***